# picture change colour on hover in html

Tags: html, image, hover

How can I make a picture change a colour when I hover over it in html? I was thinking to use a separate picture with colour as the hover but how exactly would I write this?

Comment: u know CSS? that might help u

Comment: Where is your code so far? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<img class="myPic" src="http://emjaywebdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/web_binary-300x237.jpg" />
```

**CSS:**

```
img.myPic {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

img.myPic:hover {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/usuJU/)

Or you may use different image on hover, i.e.

```
.myPic {
    background:url('path/to/image/image_normal.png') no-repeat;
}

.myPic:hover {
    background:url('path/to/image/image_hovered.png') no-repeat
}
```

[Google before you ask.](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=change%20image%20color%20on%20hover%20css&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=change%20image%20coloe%20on%20hove&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.10499j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks that's what I was after